# Play a sound when a element gets animated using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Iam trying to build basic "simon game" that has been given as a challenge in my bootcamp. now iam struck at playing sounds when an button gets animated('here my animation is fadeOut(); and fadeIn();).

Iam getting the animation but sound is not playing while the button element is animating.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simon-Game</h1>
    <main>
      <button type="button" id="green" class="green box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="red" class="red box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="yellow" class="yellow box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="blue" class="blue box"></button>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS code is:

```
var buttonColors = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];
var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var chosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(chosenColor);
  $("#" + chosenColor)
    .fadeOut(500)
    .fadeIn(500);
  $("#" + chosenColor).playSound(chosenColor);
}

function playSound(chosenColor) {
  switch (chosenColor) {
    case "green":
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3");
      audio.play();
      audio.autoplay = true;
      break;

    case "blue":
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/blue.mp3");
      audio.play();
      audio.autoplay = true;
      break;

    case "red":
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/red.mp3");
      audio.play();
      audio.autoplay = true;
      break;

    case "yellow":
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/yellow.mp3");
      audio.play();
      audio.autoplay = true;
      break;

    default:
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
      audio.play();
      audio.autoplay = true;
  }
}

nextSequence();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `playsound` function on element which you cant because its not JS object. either define onclick method in HTML and call it using click. like `$("#" + chosenColor).click();` or directly call the playsound function `playSound(chosenColor)`

Regarding playing sound you may observe that code snippet does not work here due to autoplay policy of editor. you may check working one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xhLmt8op/1/) since autoplay policy allows us to run the audio without use interaction.

please check [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) for more details on `autoplay-policy`

```js
var buttonColors = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];
var gamePattern = [];

function playSound(chosenColor) {

  switch (chosenColor) {
    case "green":
      var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");

      audio.autoplay = true;
      audio.play();
      break;

    case "blue":
      var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3");
      audio.autoplay = true;
      audio.play();
      break;

    case "red":
      var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3");
      audio.autoplay = true;
      audio.play();

    case "yellow":
      var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3");

      audio.autoplay = true;
      audio.play();

    default:
      var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3");

      audio.autoplay = true;
      audio.play();
  }
}
  function nextSequence() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var chosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(chosenColor);
    $("#" + chosenColor)
      .fadeOut(500)
      .fadeIn(500);
    // you can't call function on element.
    //*$("#" + chosenColor).playSound();

    //either define onclick method in HTML and call it using click. 
    $("#" + chosenColor).click();
    // or directly call the playsound function 
    playSound(chosenColor)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simon-Game</h1>
  <main>
    <button type="button" onclick="playSound('green')" id="green" class="green box">Green</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="playSound('red')" id="red" class="red box">Red</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="playSound('yellow')" id="yellow" class="yellow box">Yellow</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="playSound('blue')" id="blue" class="blue box">Blue</button>
  </main>
  <button onclick="nextSequence()">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but I want the sound to be played when animating the button chosen, and not on click

Comment: like i said you just cant play sound in browser unless user has interacted with it. i would suggest to add a start button which user can click thus satisfying the chrome security condition and it will play sound. check my code snippet.

Comment: basically browser wants to make sure that user has interacted with screen before autoplaying anything,

Comment: Thank you , I got it

Comment: if this helped you make sure to mark the answer as accepted and upvote! and welcome to SO :)